# Number of regular graphs of degree two

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> What Is the number of regular graphs of degree 2 on $n$ vertices?

I came up with this question in my graph theory textbook where the answer is given as the number of partitions of $n$ where each part is greater than 3; Wolfram Mathworld gives a formula in terms of the partition function without explanation...Can someone explain?How can we draw a bijection  between them?

Comment: What have you tried? What does a regular graph of degree 2 look like?

Comment: Such a graph is a disjoint union of cycles. The only question is how long they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to note that leads to partitions is the fact that if your $2$-regular graph is *connected*, then it must just be a cycle. As such, calculating the number of $2$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices amounts to counting the number of ways of dividing the vertices into groups and then ordering them into a cycle.

Comment: Can it be generalised to other degrees?

Comment: Well, the idea of partitions does extend, because we can always reduce the problem to breaking up the graph into connected components and then calculating the number of $k$-regular connected graphs, but the niceness of always having cycle graphs does not extend.